# LATEX: how to change the positon of author affliation to the bottom of first page

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, header-footer, vertical-alignment

The affliation will be placed under authors. How can i make it to the bottom of the first page not as footnote, but show like in the picture?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt,twoside, ]{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{authblk}

\linespread{1.0}
\runninghead{-Technical paper} 
\font\titlefont=cmr12 at 14pt %change the title font size
\fontfamily{helvet}\selectfont % change title font type
\title{{\vspace{5.2pt}\titlefont\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{JCI title}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
    \begin{abstract}
        \noindent \normalsize ssss
    \end{abstract}
}
\affil{Addresses of Author A}
```

[image]

Comment: please edit your question, currently the code stops at `! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \runninghead` and produces no output,

Comment: in `article` class that would normally be `\author{someone\thanks{Dept of somewhere} \and Person Two\thanks{different department}}`  but it's really impossible to guess if that is the answer you need.